# Find top 2 cities visitor goes

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

The objective is to find the 2 most popular cities travelers go to.
End result is to see which 2 cities has the highest count.

Is it shanghai + beijing or chengdu + shenyang, etc.

I'm stuck after coming down to the below dataset.

3 columns below. ID = customerid, city = cities customers traveled, row num = total cities by each traveler.

```
ID     | City    | row_num
------ | ------  | ------
177    | DALIAN  | 1
177    | SHANGHAI| 2
177    | SHENYANG| 3
291    | BEIJING | 1
291    | DALIAN  | 2
5045   | CHENGDU | 1
5045   | CHONGQIN| 2
5045   | GUANGZHO| 3
5195   | XI'AN   | 1
5195   | XIAN    | 2
```

select ID, City, row_num
from [table1]
group by ID, City, row_num

Stuck at the above table (simplified). 
But ultimately i want to show below:

```
Cities           | Occurrence
------           | ------   
shanghai+beijing | 550
------           | ------   
beijing+chengdu  | 320
------           | ------   
chengdu+shengyang| 110
```

Using SQL Server btw.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it´s a code request

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also: [edit] your question and add the query you already have.

Comment: thanks! i have updated with simple query. using SQL server btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 2 X.City
FROM (
       SELECT City,COUNT(City) as CN
       FROM [YourTable]
       GROUP BY City
                       ) X
ORDER BY X.CN DESC
```

Comment: thanks jibin! not sure how to use your suggested to achieve the result..

Comment: for eg, customer id 177 has 3 cities, so i want to display in 3 "set of city pairings"
dalian+shanghai = 1
dalian_shengyang = 1
shanghai+shengyang = 1